# Cookie-based authentication works on desktop browsers but not on mobile ones

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, axios

I'm using express.js and Sequelize for my backend and my auth route looks like this:

```js
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    Admin.findOne({
        where: {
            username: req.body.username
        }
    })
        .then(admin => {
            if (!admin) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    ERR: USER_NOT_FOUND
                });
            }

            var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
                req.body.password,
                admin.password
            );

            if (!passwordIsValid) {
                return res.status(401).send({
                    ERR: WRONG_PASSWORD
                });
            }

            const tokenBody = {
                id: admin.id,
                isMaster: (admin.username == "Master")
            };

            var token = jwt.sign(tokenBody, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: tokenExpirationTime
            });

            res.cookie('auth_token', token, {
                // 'tokenExpirationTime' is in seconds (as required for JWT), but maxAge 
                // expects milliseconds, so it must be multiplied by 1000:
                maxAge: tokenExpirationTime * 1000,
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: true
            });

            res.status(200).send({ success: true });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send({
                ERR: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            });
        });
};
```

I'm using Ejs for my front end and my sign-in code is:

```js
const signInUrl = '/api/auth/signin';
let form = document.getElementById('login');

form.onsubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData(form);
    data = {
        username: data.get('username'),
        password: data.get('password')
    };

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

    axios.post(signInUrl, data, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
            // Redirect to the home page:
            if (response.data.success)
                window.location.replace('/');
            else // console.log(response.data);
                informError(0);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            if (error.response) {
                if (error.response.data && error.response.data.ERR)
                    informError(error.response.data.ERR);
                else
                    informError(0);
            } else {
                informError(1);
            }
        });
}
```

Now the problem is that the system works completely fine on desktop browsers (I'm using it for over a month now, it passed all kinds of tests) but not on mobile browsers!

On mobile, I'm signing in and it redirects me to the home page successfully, but then, I'm still using the signin button, indicating that I'm not signed in. Also, I cannot access any protected route, receiving a "Signin Required" error!

Any help will be so appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those having the same problem, for me, the problem was showing when I was trying to access the server (on my laptop "localhost:3000") from my phone using a URL like: `http://192.168.0.107:3000`. I figured out the problem was related to the cookie being secured (`secure: true`) which was not used by the mobile browser since I was using http and not https but was used just normally by the desktop browser. So I guess deploying the app on a domain on the https protocol will solve this. But for testing purposes, just remove the `secure: true` part and it will work fine.